# Android Studio - AlertDialog button listener, and view of ProgressBar

Tags: multithreading, android-studio, android-progressbar

This is the code to test the thread and how it works! (It's not really connecting just to look like one) I wanted to add a progress bar when the alert dialog is gone by pressing the yes button, but it doesn't work. I set the Visibility to gone before, and visible to after. What seems to be the problem? I done casting right, and there's nothing wrong elsewhere. The text doesn't change also..... please help :)

```
private void connectRequest() {    

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ThreadActivity2.this);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.setMessage("Do you request Remote Access?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();

                    accessTv.setText("Requesting Remote Access ...");
                    accessPgb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5700); 

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    accessTv.setText("Server Access Successful!");
                    accessPgb.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            }).create();

    dialog.show();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit:`

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
```

To sleep for one second or

```
TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);
```

Comment: I don't understand. Where should I put them?
Is this problem has to do with sub thread not able to reach main UIs?